# 3-section transformation function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, transformation

I hope this question is new as I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I have a vector x that can be filled with any real numbers. The elements in this vector should be transformed by a function in the following way:

x = 0, if x < a

x = (x-a)/(b-a), if a <= x <= b

x = 1, if x > b

This is the function I came up with:

```
transf <- function(x, a = 0, b = 1){
  if(a > b) stop("\nThe lower bound must be smaller than the upper bound!")

  if(x < a){
    y = 0
  }
  else if(a <= x <= b){
    y = (x-a)/(b-a)
  }
  else{
    y = 1
  }
  return(y)
  print(y)
}
```

I get a bunch of error messages that I can't quite put together. I also tried replacing else if and else with a simple if, but that didn't work either.

Any help on how to solve this would be very much appreciated

Comment: Please consider to add an example of `x` too.

Comment: Maybe `ifelse` statement?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use logical indexing:

```
i.low <- x < a
i.mid <- x >= a & x <= b
i.high <- x > b
x[i.low] <- 0
x[i.mid] <- (x[i.mid] - a) / (b - a)
x[i.high] <- 1
```

Your original post didn't say what the errors were, but I'd guess you were passing the vector in as your function argument and the errors were complaining "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". This is because you're testing the condition of a vector of logicals.

Comment: Works great (probably faster too)! Thank you :)